# Laravel Algolia Search

Tags: laravel

I was install Laravel Scout with next instruction, but I have a problem :(

1) Used command `composer require laravel/scout`

2) Added into providers section `'Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider::class,'`

3) Used command `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider"`

4) Added Extends

```
Laravel\Scout\Searchable
use Searchable;
```

5) Used command `composer require algolia/algoliasearch-client-php`

6) Model has code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
use DB;

class Product extends Model
{
    use Searchable;
    protected $table = 'products';

    public static function getProductsBySearch($search)
    {
        // Список найденных продуктов
        $searchProducts = Product::search('Test')
            ->get()
            ->all();
        return $searchProducts;
    }

}
```

But Have error:

```
AlgoliaSearch requires an applicationID
```

What is Algolia? How will solve it's problem?

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure it with your [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) credentials. It is a third party service providing the full text search functionality.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scout):

> When using the Algolia driver, you should configure your Algolia id and secret credentials in your config/scout.php configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use algolia dedicated library for laravel.

[Laravel-scout-extended](https://www.algolia.com/doc/framework-integration/laravel/getting-started/introduction-to-scout-extended/#introduction)

There is cool feature like `php artisan scout:status` to see your local DB / and Index in algolia.

If you need more information as an advice you should watch this video : 
[Scout-Extended](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Jy_4sL9Iug&t=326s)

I hope it will help you.